# inherit from System.Object

Tags: c#

It is well known that C# class can inherit only from a Single Base class
How does it make sense because all classes derive from System.Object?

Also, If I look into class ValueType definition (for example), which i know that inherits directly from System.Object, i see that it is just an abstract class. i expect to see: 
public abstract class ValueType : System.Object

Comment: Classes can also inherit from classes that inherit from `Object`.  Or they can inherit from classes that inherit from classes that inherit from `Object`.  Or...

Comment: What's your question?  Yes all classes are objects and each class can only inherit from one base class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance is most easily visualized as a hierarchy or tree. See if this makes sense:

```
                     System.Object
                     /           \
                    /             \
                   /               \
MyProject.SomeClass                 MyProject.SomeBaseClass
                                         /           \
                                        /             \
                                       /               \
                   MyProject.SomeDerivedClass     MyProject.SomeOtherDerivedClass
```

Looking at `MyProject.SomeDerivedClass`, you can clearly see that it has exactly one parent in the hierarchy, its base class, `MyProject.SomeBaseClass`. Now, `MyProject.SomeBaseClass` has exactly one parent as well, `System.Object`.

While `MyProject.SomeDerivedClass` doesn't *directly* inherit from `System.Object`, its parent does; everything the parent either inherits or provides is passed on to the derived object. So, even though `MyProject.SomeDerivedClass` only inherits directly from `MyProject.SomeBaseClass`, it still inherits from `System.Object` because its parent does so.

Comment: However if I look into class ValueType definition (for example),
which i know that inherits directly from System.Object, i see that it is just an abstract class. 
i expect to see:
public abstract class ValueType : System.Object

Comment: When a class doesn't specify what its base class is, it inherits from `System.Object` by default. That's why `public abstract class ValueType` and `public abstract class ValueType : System.Object` are identical.

Answer (score 21):

> It is well known that C# class can inherit only from a single base class.

That is not well-known because that statement is absolutely false. In C# a class can inherit members from arbitrarily many base classes and interfaces.

You have confused the *inherits-members-from-type* relationship with the *directly-derives-from-type* relationship.

The actual rule is that every class except System.Object *derives directly* from exactly one class. System.Object is unique in that it is the only class that derives directly from nothing.

Every class and every interface can derive directly from arbitrarily many interfaces.

A class or interface *inherits* the members of every class or interface that it derives from, either directly or indirectly. The "direct or indirect derivation" relationship is the *transitive closure* of the direct derivation relationship.

Answer (score 12):

Because you are inheriting **indirectly** from object; for example

```
Object <= Foo <= Bar <= Blap
```

Hence object is the root of all **managed** types (but not quite all types; raw unsafe pointers do not inherit from object, for example).

Comment: Inheritance arrows usually point the other way...

Comment: @henk fine I'll fix them. In all honesty, I never get very excited by such things. My uml sucks majorly:

Comment: OK, I'll shut up about the arrow styles then.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever base class you inherit from, eventually you will indirectly derive from `System.Object`

so for example

```
public myConreteClass : myBaseClass
{}

public myBaseClass : System.Object
{}
```

However long the chain goes on the either bottom class that may or may not inherit from something will inherit from System.Object

Answer (score 1):

Class A derives from Class B which derives from System.Object.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

The key word there is *hierarchy*.

So this means that (in some imaginary application) a class called `Cat` could inherit from `Mammal` which might inherit from `Animal`, which would then inherit from `System.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

All classes inherit from object since if we have

```
public class Foo {}
```

This is the same as writing:

```
public class Foo : object {}
```

And if Bar subclasses Foo:

```
public class Bar : Foo {}
```

Then we're still good, since Foo inherits from object, so does Bar.

Answer (score 1):

C# class can inherit from only a single Base class and other classes can inherit from the same class too, so multiple classes can inherit from the same class but each calss inherit from only one class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this inheriting from one type at the time:

let's say you have a type Object

```
public class Object { }
```

then you have a type called `String`, you can have string inheriting from object

```
public class String : Object { }
```

Then you create a class called `StringWithColors` inheriting from String

```
public class StringWithColors : String { }
```

at this point, your new class `StringWithColors` will have inherited from `String` and `Object`.. and so on...